# how to add class="lazyload" and data-sizes="auto" with javascript?

Tags: javascript

[image: add class="lazyload" and data-sizes="auto"]

here I have an img element (view from tinycloud), then I want to add data-sizez="auto" and class="lazyload" attributes with javascript.

```js
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 img.setAttribute("class", "lazyload");
 img.setAttribute("data-sizes", "auto");
 document.body.appendChild(img);
```

I've tried it as above, but still can't. What is the correct way to add data-sizez="auto" and class="lazyload" attributes with javascript ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('img')
for (const element of elements) {
  element.setAttribute('data-sizes', 'auto')
  element.classList.add('lazyload')
}
```

This code will add `lazyload` class and `data-sized="auto"` to all `<img />` elements in the document

Comment: but, how to make the selected img element only the img element in the card-body class ?

Comment: you can add more css selectors in the querySelectorAll argument, I think it's `querySelectorAll('.card-body img')`